# Assigning a default value through the logical operator OR

Tags: javascript, function, default-value

We know that the javascript logical operator || produces the value of its first operand if the first operand is *true*. Otherwise, it produces the value of the second operand.

So in this example:

```
<script language="javascript">
function test (value){
    this.value = value || "(value not given)";
}
</script>
```

if the parameter *value* passed to the function is treated as *false* like the integer *0* or the empty string *""* then *this.value* will be set to (*value not given)* which is not <s>true</s> correct (because indeed we are passing a value).

So the question is which should be the best way to set *this.value*?

**EDIT**: All 4 first answers use the ternary operator "?". My question is about "||" operator.

Comment: I didn't get your question. `"(value not given)"` coerces to `true`.

Comment: Please explain what you meant when you said "`this.value` will be set to `(value not given)` which is __not__ `true`".

Comment: @aadit-m-shah `(value not given)` is the default value to be assigned when the parameter `value` is treated as false. There is no error on this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scheme with `||` is the most convenient to write, but it can ONLY be used when a falsey value (`undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `false`, `NaN`) is not a legitimate value. (When you just want to deal with `null` and `undefined`, you can use the new nullish coalescing operator (`??`) described [in this proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) and included in ES2020.)

If you want to allow specific falsey values and not allow others, then you have to write more specific code to handle your specific cases.  For example, if you wanted to allow an empty string, but not allow null or undefined or other falsey values, then you'd have to write more specific code like this:

```
function test(value) {
    if (value || value === "") {
        this.value = value;
    } else {
        this.value = "(value not given)";
    }
}
```

Or if you only want to exclude only `undefined`, you can test for it specifically:

```
function test(value) {
    if (value === undefined) {
        value = "(value not given)";
    }
    this.value = value;
}
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Your if statement should be as follows: `if (value || value === "")`.

Comment: @AaditMShah - Corrected the typo.

Comment: Your first statement makes much sense. I agree with you. || operator it's not usable in some cases. Good answer, thanks!

Comment: You don't need the "etc..." in the list of falsey values, you listed them all.

Comment: @Julian - I removed the "etc...".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what values you want to exclude. If the "general false values" are too broad of a category, you can be more explicit:

```
function test(value) {
    this.value = value !== undefined ? value : "(value not given)";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to assign falsey values do this.

```
this.value = (typeof value !== 'undefined') ? value : 'value not given';
```

This will retain values like `false`, `''`, and `0`, but will use the default when the value is actually not passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript">
function test (value){
    this.value = arguments.length > 0 ? value : "(value not given)";
}
</script>
```

You can check to see if that argument was passed in by checking that functions arguments array's length.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is:

```
this.value = (typeof value == 'undefined') ? 'my argument' : value;
```

Probably duplicate question.
Google it.

Answer (score 0):

Today depending on the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_functions_default_parameters) your application cares about, you might want to use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) instead:

```
var test = (value = '(value not given)') => {
    this.value = value;
};
```

This is relevant today, also there has not been an update to the question and answers date since 2011 so I thought it might help.